# Create new window in tcl/tk

Tags: user-interface, tcl, tk-toolkit

How can i create a same gui every time by clicking the button without closing current one?

```
wm title . "abcd"
wm geometry . 50x50
pack [button .b -text "new"]
```

Please help me.

Comment: What should happen when the first GUI is closed? Should all the other ones created by pushing the `new` button close as well?

Comment: yes, all the windows will be closed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `toplevel` command creates a new window for you to put widgets in. It's a good idea to use a procedure for building the overall GUI in that window:

```
wm title . "abcd"
wm geometry . 50x50
pack [button .b -text "new" -command makeWindow]
set counter 0

proc makeWindow {} {
    # Make a unique widget name
    global counter
    set w .gui[incr counter]

    # Make the toplevel
    toplevel $w
    wm title $w "This is $w"

    # Put a GUI in it
    pack [label $w.xmpl -text "This is an example"]
    pack [button $w.ok -text OK -command [list destroy $w]]
}
```

Each of these windows that you make is as independent or dependent on the others as you want. It depends on how you write the code, arrange the variables, design the callbacks, etc.